# RStudio Code Not Working In Kaggle (weekdays and months function)

Tags: r, lubridate, kaggle

I have code that works fine in RStudio Desktop but when I tried to put it into a Kaggle Notebook I get Errors.

I'm using the months and weekdays function from lubridate to convert date values into their respective months and days.

```
casWeekDayStart <- weekdays(myCasData$started_at)
table(casWeekDayStart)
```

I get the error

```
Error in UseMethod("weekdays"): no applicable method for 'weekdays' applied to an object of class "character"
Traceback:

1. weekdays(myCasData$started_at)
```